# path setting appears twice in env output

Tags: macos, shell, path, environment-variables, sudo

After an OS version upgrade I have the following strange problem:

```
% port
MacPorts 2.3.1
...

% sudo -i
# port
MacPorts 2.3.1

% sudo port
sudo: port: command not found
```

Furthermore, if I do it all from within tmux, port works there as well, so it might not be related to the version upgrade.

The only difference I found between the environment inside tmux and outside (while running sudo) is that `sudo env` outside tmux gives two entries: one is my regular, correct, entry, and the second is `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`, which apparently destroys the correct path.

What could be adding the second line? and how is it even possible to have those two lines?

*Note*: Additional checking found that the second setting is here even without using sudo (when not under tmux). I don't understand this...

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure about the 2 PATH entries, but I think you want to run `sudo -i port`, not just `sudo port`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I've never seen `sudo -i XXX` used in generic instructions. I also don't see why it would be necessary to run ports from root's environment. As an example, here is a random quote from a random page that I had open: `sudo port install portname +variant1 +variant2 …` from [MacPorts Wiki](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration).

Comment: I also ran into the same problem, two PATH entries defined in env. really weird. Appeared after upgrading to yosemite.